# cobalt(RELEASE 9,gold) render Conformance of qual-e page only, other not

Tags: cobalt

We build cobalt that is official release and branch is RELEASE 9 with gold.
Cobalt can render qual-e page and we can enter Conformance item.
But other items can not render.
After a mouse click, nothing happens.

So we built a cobalt RELEASE 9 with qa.
Cobalt can render Conformance, EME, MSE and Progressive.

Do you know which build flag we can use to pass a qual-e certificate?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following link for the answers.
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cobalt-dev/e5l9VJcMSUY/A1An5ApeAwAJ

Comment: hi  Daniel Juyung Seo, we know this "[Announcement] Cobalt 9 Release" that you point url. but it did not specify which build flag we can use to pass Qual-e.

Comment: The build type shouldn't matter. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cobalt-dev/e5l9VJcMSUY/dMTyy4VlAwAJ